# HasDefaultSchema is not recognized even with System.Data.Entity on the namespace

Tags: c#, .net

I want create a dbCotext and model according to my schema and view but I get the error:

```
public CarContext() : base(nameOrConnectionString: "LTtest") { }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("wpv");   
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
public DbSet<v_run_tt> v_run { get; set; }
```

I need to write schema name, is there any other way? I'm using PostgreSQL and entityframework 4

Comment: Are you using EFCore or EF6?

Comment: @Sakuto entity framework  4.1.0.0

Comment: Look like it was not implemented before EF6 : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbmodelbuilder.hasdefaultschema(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: @Sakuto thanks,can you tell me what else i can do to write the schema?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679488(v=vs.113).aspx Looks like toTable can take the schema name as the second parameter

Comment: @Sakuto works! thanks can i ask another question?

Comment: You have to create a new question for that, don't post it in the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HasDefaultSchema` is only available in EFG 6+ ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbmodelbuilder.hasdefaultschema(v=vs.113).aspx ).

However, you can use the second parameter of `toTable` to specify the schema name. `toTable("tableName", "schemaName");`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679488(v=vs.113).aspx